# Android resource linking failed ; Invalid symbol name: id/null

Tags: android, gradle

help i was just coding for shape.xml at my application but when i run it this happens.. help i dont really know what to do. and i dont know why this happens.. please i need your help all ty. when i tried to delete/undo all my codes it still happens

```
Android resource linking failed
Output:  C:\Users\KHALESSI-JB\AndroidStudioProjects\ReminderApplication\app\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\com\example\khalessi_jb\reminderapplication\R.java: error: invalid symbol name 'com.example.khalessi_jb.reminderapplication:id/null'.

Command: C:\Users\KHALESSI-JB\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\b0f95379c78a264df14bf14d8fac21f6\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe link -I\
    C:\Users\KHALESSI-JB\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-28\android.jar\
    --manifest\
    C:\Users\KHALESSI-JB\AndroidStudioProjects\ReminderApplication\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\processDebugManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml\
    -o\
    C:\Users\KHALESSI-JB\AndroidStudioProjects\ReminderApplication\app\build\intermediates\processed_res\debug\processDebugResources\out\resources-debug.ap_\
    -R\
    @C:\Users\KHALESSI-JB\AndroidStudioProjects\ReminderApplication\app\build\intermediates\incremental\processDebugResources\resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
    --auto-add-overlay\
    --java\
    C:\Users\KHALESSI-JB\AndroidStudioProjects\ReminderApplication\app\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\
    --custom-package\
    com.example.khalessi_jb.reminderapplication\
    -0\
    apk\
    --output-text-symbols\
    C:\Users\KHALESSI-JB\AndroidStudioProjects\ReminderApplication\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug\R.txt\
    --no-version-vectors
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0
```

Comment: Did you set one of your IDs in your XML to `null`?

Comment: ya... i just found it after i posted this one... sorry... btw how to close this question?

Comment: You can delete it https://pasteboard.co/IJVj2b7.png